# (Beginner) can't run program as name after chmoding

Tags: linux, bash

Imagine I have a python3 script named `program`. When I want to run program, I want to do `chmod +x program` then `program` to run it. Instead, I get an error as if it wasn't chmoded, `-bash: program: command not found`. How can I fix this? NOTE: `./program` works, I just don't like doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is `program` is not in your $PATH. So you have to use the `./program` to tell the shell you want to execute the executable `program` in the current directory.

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054538/add-a-bash-script-to-path) stackoverflow question for more detail on adding scripts to your path. But simply put you put your script in a folder say `bin` in your home directory. Then in your `.bashrc` profile add in `PATH=$PATH:~/bin`. Place your script in bin and then type in `source .bashrc` and now you can just type `program`.